# How to fix Maven PermGen out of memory error on Travis-ci?

Tags: java, maven, out-of-memory, travis-ci

I'm getting PermGen out of memory error on every build at travis-ci. This is my configuration file:

```
language: java
env:
  global:
    - MAVEN_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx4g"
script: mvn clean install
```

Looks like `MAVEN_OPTS` is not working, since the same values on another server make the build successful.

Here is one of the builds: https://travis-ci.org/tpc2/requs/builds/23383360

Comment: Note: if yo can, cosider to migrate to Oracle's Java SE 8, which removed the PermGen altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Your build link is no longer valid, so I'm going to make a guess. Are you getting the PermGen during surefire tests? That plugin uses a separately configured arg line. Our builds are configured like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>${argLine} -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set JVM memory settings in MAVEN_OPTS by adding this to `.travis.yml`:

```
before_install: echo "MAVEN_OPTS='-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m'" > ~/.mavenrc
```

Comment: This is ignored by forked processes such as the surefire plugin, but does work for Maven itself.